# First time running issue in ef6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an application with 45 entities. And one of them has a recursive relationship.

This is my dbContext class:

```
public class Context: DbContext
{
    public Context()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        base.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Level>().HasMany(l => l.Children).WithOptional(l => l.Parent).HasForeignKey(l => l.ParentId);
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

This is my `Level` class that has a recursive relation:

```
public class Level
{
    public int LevelId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Level Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Level> Children { get; set; }
}
```

But I have a big issue that my first time running takes a long time. In localhost it takes 10 seconds and in the server it takes 20 to 30 seconds to respond.

Whats the problem?

Comment: Is the DB running on the same host?

Comment: Have you confirmed that it is the same table reference which is causing the problem?

Comment: @Robert No. In localhost the db is in my local sql and in server the db is in the server.

Comment: @kjbartel I dont know at all. I am not sure yet that the problem is from the Level table or not.

Comment: Unless you're using a dedicated server it may be the case that it just takes that long. You could run some benchmark queries directly on the DB's to compare the performance of your local system and the server.

Comment: @Robert Of course the server side would take longer time but its about 30 seconds for the first time! Its not good at all.

Comment: By 'first time' do you mean when you create all the entities? Or first time after you've created the entities, if so what query are you executing that takes so long?

Comment: Well you need to show what steps you've taken to work out the problem yourself. Currently we only know that you have 45 entities and one of them has a reference to itself in a parent child relationship. That's not enough information. Don't guess. Debug.

Comment: @PaulZahra I mean the first time that the dbContext constracts and create entities. I mean after IIS recycles.

Comment: @kjbartel I just have researched about it and I think I should cache dbContext but I am not sure about doing it and I dont know how to do it too.

Comment: @HamidReza Are you running in Debug mode? There is a known issue with lazy in debug mode. I believe theres a fix in 6.0.2... which version are you running?

Comment: @PaulZahra Its 6.1.1.How to disable Debug mode?

Comment: Read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815157 also maybe look into putting optimizeCompilations="true" in your web.config.... gotta run... bug fix time in my job :D

Comment: @PaulZahra Thank you for spending your time but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: if you mention EF6, have you just switched to EF6? if true, you may know, in EF6 the default behavior changed. it treats everything as transaction

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem of view building for the initialization of the context.

try read http://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/2014/07/09/three-steps-for-fast-entityframework-6.1-first-query-performance/ to see how to improve first launch, by pre generate the views for example.